# libraries mismatch between application and plugins

Tags: openssl, linker, shared-libraries

I have an application (imsd server) that dynamically loads a plugin I'm maintaining, that's releases as a shared library.

The whole thing is running on Centos7.3.1611

The problem apparently is that the application is statically linked against an old version of openssl (supposedly 1.0.1k I'm waiting for confirmation) and the plugin needs at least 1.1.

I tried both statically and dynamically linking the plugin against libssl and libcrypto, but when it's executed it finds the symbols (i.e. OPENSSL_LH_insert) already loaded by the application and segfaults because the function behaves differently between 1.0 and 1.1.

I'm afraid there is no solution, since the whole thing is a mess, unfortunately both the main application and the system configuration are not under my control.

Though maybe there's something I don't know or understand about Linux linking and there's a way to magically solve it.

Thank you.

I tried linking the plugin against libssl.a and libcrypto.a, or specifying the dynamic version I want using -l:libcrypto.1.1.1 -l:libssl:1.1.1
In both cases it still crashes during the ssl_add_all_ciphers_int phase.
I also tried not linking libssl at all, but in that case it doesn't load because it's missing symbols that are not present in the old version of ssl.
I could try modifying the plugin to use an older libssl but it would be a real pain and I'm not sure it would work.